# System.out.println() not working in windows

Tags: java, windows

Thank you for your replays.
I'm writing this code using eclipse on ububntu OS.

this is my code:

```
public class test{
     public static void main (String[] args){
             System.out.print("Hello world");
     }
}
```

Then make it by using eclipse export JAR Executable file.

I run the code under ubuntu terminal like this:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

so I got the Hello world string, and this is the result:
[Screen shot on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61sFI.png)

And running the same command on the command prompt of windwos 8.1 x86.

```
java -jar test.jar
```

And the result is this: [Result on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UANk.png)

Thank you again for helping.

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Show the full code (since it's a simple hello world program it should be quite short). Tell us what IDE and compiler and version of Windows you're using.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you with your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the classpath issue , use below code to run. -verbose will print you the execution details.

```
set classpath=.;
java -verbose -jar helloworld.jar
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pankaj Pandey,
I executed the set " classpath=.; " then when I run my jar file I can got the result!

Comment: @JohnKangari You should also get the result if you would run your correctly. You said you used `java -jar test.jar` which seems to be incorrect, since the screenshot clearly shows that you just used `test.jar`.

Comment: @Tom Your are right but I have test both of them, as you see there is no errors because of the java is in my path, If I'm not wrong.

Comment: @JohnKangari It may depends on how you configured Windows to handle jar files. So it may or may not work, but in this case: you may don't need to set the classpath, you just need to start the jar you like you said you did (but did differently).

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry Tom you are right I test again test.jar not working form me but it's working as java -jar test.jar.
But I'm sure I have tested this one too but it's not worked!
Anyway, thanks for taking the time to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your code and the way you run it.

First idea: make sure you run your code on the command line:

- open DOS box
- cd to the directory where your .jar file is
- java -jar helloworld.jar

You might not see any console output if you double-click the .jar file

Comment: He might run the program without using a .jar file, so `java helloworld` (after compiling via `javac helloworld.java`) might be enough. :)

Comment: No I know that, I'm running as you noted:
java -jar test.jar (where test is my file name)

Comment: @LardAnomander OP clearly explained that he was packaging it in a .jar file.